# Adding class to current child when click on parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have ecommerce site, trying open sub-menu when click on parent menu
In category side-bar when parent element (main category) is clicked i want add class to child element (sub-category) so that child element is display with some nice animation.
[categories menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvF6n.png)

when next main category is click previous sub-category should be hidden and current sub-category should be displayed.

```
<ul class="woo-main-cat">

<li class="cork"><a href="http://maincategories">Anti-Allergics</a>
    <ul class="sub-cat-menu">
      <li><a href="http://maincategoreis/sub-categories)</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="cork"><a href="http://maincategories">Anti-Allergics</a>
    <ul class="sub-cat-menu">
      <li><a href="http://maincategoreis/sub-categories)</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://maincategoreis/sub-categories)</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="cork"><a href="http://maincategories">Anti-Allergics</a>
    <ul class="sub-cat-menu">
      <li><a href="http://maincategoreis/sub-categories)</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://maincategoreis/sub-categories)</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Where class:woo-main-cat > li holds main categories and class:sub-cat-menu > li holds sub-categories. When woo-main-cat > li is click sub-cat-menu should displayed when next main categories is clicked previous sub-category should be close.

```
.sub-cat-menu {


background: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: 0.8s ease-in;
}

.tako-open{
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Trying some animation effect with css when sub-categories opens and hide

```
$('.woo-main-cat li').on('click', function(){
$(this).children('.sub-cat-menu').addClass('tako-open');
});
```

Above code perfectly open the current sub-category adding tako-open class on child element->sub-cat-menu when click on parent category but i want close this open sub-category when next parent category is click.

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('.woo-main-cat li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).children('.sub-cat-menu').addClass('tako-open');
},function() {
       $(this).children('.sub-cat-menu').removeClass('tako-open');
    });
});
```

so after adding removeClass code nothing happens it doesnt add any class to child-element (sub-category) when click on parent element (main-category)

Comment: Your attempt to pass two functions via `.on()` there makes no sense; it takes _one_ handler function. Looks like you confused this with the `.hover()` method perhaps? That one takes _two_ handler functions.

Comment: You can simply remove the class from whichever element currently has it, if you just do it _before_ you add the class to the current element. Just select it _based on_ it having that class.

Comment: Please click [edit] and then `[<>]` and make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first remove the `tako-open` class from all the elements before opening the current one.

```js
$('.woo-main-cat > li').on('click', function(){
  $('.sub-cat-menu').removeClass('tako-open');
  $(this).children('.sub-cat-menu').addClass('tako-open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.woo-main-cat li').on('click', function(){
$( "*" ).removeClass( "tako-open" );
$(this).children('.sub-cat-menu').addClass('tako-open',1000, "easeOutBounce");
    })
```

- will remove all tako-open classes. ppreciate everyone's help